# Live Tacking with Google Bigtable

Tags: bigdata, event-tracking, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

My use case for using google big table is that i have to do live tracking on all the device of connected to server (live bus on root from point A to B and tracking them). Every 5 sec each device emit some data I have to store that all data in google Big table and get data from google big table to show live traffic every 5 sec. Is this a good use case for google big table.

Comment: How many devices do you have connected to the server? Most propably any database will do the job, no need for big table!

Comment: Number of can increase with time . Currently about 30,000. If you can suggestion some other database.

Comment: I would suggest looking into InfluxDB.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Bigtable is great at tackling time-series data, like you have.  30K machines with 5 requests per second means 30K / 5S = 6K rows written per second.  The smallest Cloud Bigtable cluster of 3 nodes can handle 30K rows per second.

The cluster can scale with both your projected growth of writes plus what ever you'll be doing to read data out of Cloud Bigtable.

You can use your own time-series implementation (you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series) for some ideas about schema design), or you can use [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/) [with Cloud Bigtable](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/backends/bigtable.html).

[Cost](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/pricing) is a consideration.  Each node costs 65¢/hr (you can calculate the cost of a 3 node cluster).